# TAR command produces 0kb file after completing

Tags: linux, tar

In linux i have this code:

```
touch –t 202108010101 some_file 
find . -newer some_file -print0 | xargs -0 tar cfz //mnt/wss/anva-abs-from-01-08.tar
```

Wich produces an tar file for everything earlier than 01-08-2021(august 1st 2021)
But for some reason after it is complete or almost complete it doesnt trow any errors but the file in windows goes back to 0kb(it was 300GB before)

someone knows why that is?

Comment: xargs is not the way to go, it will call tar multiple times (depending on max arg count). better go with process substitution or pipe it to tar --null -T -

Comment: btw file name should be tar.gz